# Cannot read fetch data on express server

Tags: javascript, express

On the client side, I have an application based on threejs an d javascript. I want to send data to the server written in express using fetch. Unfortunately, the server does not receive the data and the browser also gives an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

Application:

```
this.username = prompt("Username:");
const body = JSON.stringify({ username: this.username });
fetch("http://localhost:3000/addUser", { method: "POST", body })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(
        (data) => (
            console.log(data), (this.aktualny_album_piosenki = data.files)
        )
    );
```

Server:

```
var express = require("express")
var app = express()
const PORT = 3000;
var path = require("path");
app.use(express.static('dist'));
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.post("/addUser", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

Comment: this might be an issue with CORS try enabling it in headers

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but maybe try... (very bottom of your main server file)

```
app.listen((PORT) => {
   console.log(`app is listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

is required maybe? I have this chunk of code in every project of my own so maybe that could fix the server not recognizing the api request

[express documentation on app listen](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen)

heres what I use typically... this is a boilerplate for every one of my projects

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const connectDB = require("./config/db.js");
const router = express.Router();
const config = require("config");
// init middleware
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoDB = require("./config/db.js");
const path = require("path");
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    }
});
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const helmet = require("helmet");
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoDB();

app.options('*', cors());
app.use('*', cors());
app.use(cors());

const limitSize = (fn) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.path === '/upload/profile/pic/video') {
            fn(req, res, next);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
}


const limiter = rateLimit({
    max: 100,// max requests
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000 * 1000, // remove the last 1000 for production
    message: 'Too many requests' // message to send
});

app.use(xss());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(mongoSanitize());
app.use(limiter);

// app.use routes go here... e.g. app.use("/login", require("./routes/file.js");

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname, './client/public/index.html')
})

app.get('*', cors(), function(_, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
      };
    };
});

app.get('/*', cors(), function(_, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
        if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
        };
    };
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    // Express will serve up production files
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));
    // serve up index.html file if it doenst recognize the route
    app.get('*', cors(), function(_, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
        if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    }
    })
    app.get('/*', cors(), function(_, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/build/index.html'), function(err) {
        if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
    })
}; 


io.on("connection", socket => {

    console.log("New client connected");

    socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("Client disconnected"));
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});


client-side fetch request looks good to me its prob a server/express.JS thing but like i said i may be wrong but worth trying
```